# VSCode metals, run specific ten in scalatest

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scala-metals

is there a way in vscode with metals scala plugin, run specific test scenario ?
Like in IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean specific test clause in say a scalatest class, I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".

Workaround could be to add a launch configuration and pass args to just run the test you want with -z: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html#via-a-launchjson-configuration

Or just ignore-tag the others.